# Image scrolling on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, css-animations, transition

I want to make an image inside div to scroll down on hover. And that part is working.

Also, I need to make that it scroll longer if the image is longer and because of that I was trying to use calc inside of transition, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```css
.preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.previewimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.n2odesigns.com/wp-
 content/uploads/Projema-Website-Preview-2016.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position-y: 0;
  transition: all calc(0.02s * height) ease-in-out;
}

.previewimg:hover {
  background-position-y: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all calc(0.02s * height) ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
  <div class="previewimg"></div>
</div>
```

If there is some other better way to do this I can use it too.

Comment: you cannot do something like this with the time of transition. You may try JS

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, but is there some other way with transform? I know it is possible with js, but wanted to try with css.

Comment: i don't thing you can dynamically get height of element using CSS and transform it into a value to be used with `calc` : this is more programming than styling which is not the purpose of CSS

Comment: i thought you didn't want to use JS ...

Comment: check my last sentence, thanks anyway Temani.

Comment: here is your last sentence `I know it is possible with js, but wanted to try with css` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok to do this you need it to be an image only not a background image, to do this transition duration based on height functionality, please use the below code.

```js
$('.previewimg').css("transition", "transform " + 0.02 * $('.previewimg').height() + "s ease");
```

```css
.preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.preview .previewimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: translateY(0px); 
}

.preview:hover .previewimg {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 300px)); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
  <img class="previewimg" src="https://www.n2odesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Projema-Website-Preview-2016.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are accepting JS as a solution then here is a code you can add without changing your HTML/CSS structure :

```js
function getHeight(url) {
  console.log(url);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  return 0.002*parseInt(img.height);
}
var e =$(".previewimg");
var tr = "all "+getHeight(e.css("background-image").replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1'))+"s ease-in-out";
console.log(tr);
e.css('transition',tr);
```

```css
.preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.previewimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.n2odesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Projema-Website-Preview-2016.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position-y: 0;
}

.previewimg:hover {
  background-position-y: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
  <div class="previewimg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually use javascript for it.
it's codepen : [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ouzkagan/pen/RwaPGej) or it's the css code for you code:

```
.preview {
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.previewimg{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/500x1500/);
   transition: background-position 2s ease-out;
}
 .preview:hover .previewimg{
   background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add other body elements with the styles classes name. And it make a boxes that when we hover the logo is changed. The logo is changes on hover.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logoses{ 
    text-align: center; 
    list-style: none; 
}
.logoses .logo{
    width: 178px;
    height: 75px;
    background:
    url('G:/touqeer/amp-landing-pages/assets/images/clients_logo.png') center top no-repeat;
    margin: 0 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
    }
#amara{
    background-position: 5px -125px;
}
#amara:hover{
    background-position: 5px 0px;
}
#ge{
    background-position: -1486px -125px;  
}
#ge:hover{
    background-position: -1486px -2px;
}
#nuance{
    background-position: -489px -124px;  
}
#nuance:hover{
    background-position: -489px -1px;
}
#gilson{
    background-position: -329px -123px;
}
#gilson:hover{
    background-position: -329px 0px;
}
#pcs_wireless{
    background-position:  -824px -125px; 
}
#pcs_wireless:hover{
    background-position:  -824px -2px;
}
#herbalife{
    background-position: -161px -123px;
}
#herbalife:hover{
    background-position:-161px 0px;
}
#pcf{
    background-position: -659px -125px;  
}
#pcf:hover{
    background-position: -659px -2px;
}
#seimens{
    background-position: -991px -125px;
}
#seimens:hover{
    background-position:-991px -2px;
}
#melesta_games{
    background-position:  -1156px -124px;  
}
#melesta_games:hover{
    background-position:  -1156px 1px;
}
#samsung{
    background-position: -1324px -123px;
}
#samsung:hover{
    background-position: -1324px 0px;
}
.center_pd{
    padding: 75px 0px;
}
.text_bottom{
    margin: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
}
.center_text{
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 30px ;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #393939;
}
.prg{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Open Sans;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too.